# Shopify: Testing on Localhost in windows

Tags: windows, localhost, shopify, liquid

I've been trying for a while now to find any solution to try and test shopify themes on localhost so I don't screw up a live site I'm going to be maintaining. The only thing I can even remotely find is Vision, but it's only for Mac OS. I can download the theme I need, but I can't seem to find out a way to get it to load through localhost. Any ideas? Or is this a fruitless search?

Answer (score 1):

For at least 5 years all the cool kids have been developing themes using newer options like for example the lightweight Ruby scripts in the [**serve gem**](http://get-serve.com/) as one example. Or using any static site generator with something like [**Pow**](http://pow.cx/). IMHO it is a **very last resort** to use WAMP or LAMP for any kind of theme generation development cycle. Not least because theme generation does **NOT** require any database.

Answer (score 0):

Its not what your asking for, but its a nice alternative / plugin if you use Sublime Text Editor:
https://bitbucket.org/dwarburton/sublimeshopify

You can create a developers account here: http://www.shopify.com/partners for creating 'test' stores.

This allows you to edit the files **locally** and they are pushed live to your test store.